# UIButton setBackgroundImage back to default

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, uistoryboard

I have a normal RoundedRect UIButton that I created in a UIStoryBoard. Under a certain situation I call `setBackgroundImage` on the button to change it's appearance. How do I then change the appearance of the UIButton back to what it was before setting the background image (the default RoundedRect look)? Calling  `[button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];` seems to result in a button with no background at all (completely transparent).

Thanks,
Max

Comment: It depends on the original look. You can set back the background image...

Comment: It's a normal RoundedRect UIButton. I forgot to put that in the question. I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know, when you set UIButton to RoundedRect, you tell your app to set the default image as the background of your button.

If you then change this background with a custom image, your app puts away the default image, and switches it with the new one.

Unfortunately, your app doesn't remember what was the look of your button before changing it, and it is not possible to go back.

Anyway, you can reset your UIButton these ways:

> 1. Deleting and creating it again
> 2. Creating a custom background image that looks like RoundedRect UIButton
> 3. Using UIControlStates to set the appearance of your button